# CSS classes overlapping?

Tags: css, class, overlapping

this is the basics I know, but I can't seem to solve this. this is the code (snippet)

```
    ul#storage_list, ul.sub_folder{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
        font-size: 12px;

    }

            ul#storage_list li{
                margin:0;
                line-height: 20px;
                display:block;
                cursor:pointer;
            }

                ul#storage_list li.file span.name{
                    background:url("/larea/site_images/file.png") left no-repeat;
                    padding-left: 20px;
                }

                ul#storage_list li.dir span.name{
                    margin-left:5px;
                    background:url("/larea/site_images/folder.png") left no-repeat;
                    padding-left: 20px;
                }

                    ul#storage_list li.dir span.pin{
                    background:url("/larea/site_images/folder_arrow.png") left no-repeat #fff;
                    width:10px;
                    height: 10px;
                    display: inline-block;
                    }

ul.sub_folder{
    margin-left:15px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    font-size: 12px;

}               

            ul.sub_folder li{
                margin:0;
                line-height: 20px;
                display:block;
                cursor:pointer;
            }

                ul.sub_folder li.file span.name{
                    background:url("/larea/site_images/file.png") left no-repeat;
                    padding-left: 20px;
                }

                ul.sub_folder li.dir span.name{
                    margin-left:5px;
                    background:url("/larea/site_images/folder.png") left no-repeat;
                    padding-left: 20px;
                }
                    ul.sub_folder li.dir span.pin{
                    background:url("/larea/site_images/folder_arrow.png") left no-repeat;
                    width:10px;
                    height: 10px;
                    display: inline-block;
                    }   

    </style>

    </head>
        <body> 
            <ul id="storage_list">
                <li class="dir"><span class="pin"></span><span class="name">omg</span>
                    <ul class="sub_folder">
                        <li class="dir"><span class="pin"></span><span class="name">omg</span></li>
                        <li class="file"><span class="pin"></span><span class="name">omg2</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="file"><span class="pin"></span><span class="name">omg2</span></li>
            </ul>
```

it happens that ALL the `<li>` (whatever the class of the li) inside `<ul class="sub_folder">` get the same style as `<li class="dir">` inside `<ul id="storage_list">` ... they all get the `.dir` class.
Why?

EDIT: I did it! Is there a way to vote or reward myself? It's the third time I solve my own problems when nobody answers :) Kidding.
For community spirit the problem was that since the class `.sub_folder` was inside the parent `#storage_list` and a rule for the the sub `<li>` was set, all the `<li>` (no matter if inside another ) were getting the same styles also. The solution was to use `>` so that ONLY the parent `<li>` will get the specific class and not the children, grandchildren etc..
So the rule (example) becomes `ul#storage_list > li.dir > span.name`

Comment: Have you validated your html to check for any nesting issues?  Can you post it?

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question below -points down- and it'll get upvoted if people like it :)

Comment: But inefficient CSS selectors btw. You should dig into it. http://www.google.com/search?q=efficient+css+selectors

Comment: You mean repeated rules? I'm taking care of it, other than that what in specific?

Comment: @Sandro - if you've solved your own issue, you can write the solution as an answer below, and then click the 'Accepted' tick button to mark it as the right answer. This will be your way of 'rewarding yourself' as you ask, and also tells the rest of us that the problem has been solved so we don't need to come to help. :)

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul#storage_list > li.dir > span.name
{
    margin-left:5px;
    background:url("/larea/site_images/folder.png") left no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```